# Compiling program with dll libraries

Tags: c++, dll, dllimport

I use WinInet libraries. To make the program work properly, I must install the MS Redistributable Package, otherwise an error will pop up. Is it possible to compile a library with a program to make it work without installing the libraries?

Answer (score 2):

The MS Redistributable package is the VC runtime, it is unrelated to the use of `wininet.dll`.
An option would be to statically link the VC runtime ([`MT` compiler switch, instead of `MD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/2kzt1wy3%28v=vs.80%29)).

Comment: Yes, but if I compile with MT key, I see error:
IntelliSense: #error directive: Please use the /MD switch for _AFXDLL builds